# regex to find numbers with slash

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have some numbers within sentences and they look like this

```
s='rare blond Canadian terrier on wheels. Only $8.98. test test. ...0.1/10 very rare'

patt='[0-9\.{1}]*/10'
re.findall(patt,s)
```

i want to find float/10 ( or sometimes int/10) , but with my pattern i got

```
['...1/10']
```

im sure this should be an easy fix, anyone please help?

Comment: why not `"\d+\.?\d*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?/10
```

- `\d+` matches one or more digits
- The optional (`?`) non-captured group `(?:\.\d+)` matches a `.` followed by one or more digits
- `/10` matches literal `/10`

**Example:**

```
In [72]: str_ = 'rare blond Canadian terrier on wheels. Only $8.98. test test. ...0.1/10 very rare'

In [73]: re.search(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?/10', str_).group()
Out[73]: '0.1/10'

In [74]: str_ = 'rare blond Canadian terrier on wheels. Only $8.98. test test. ...23/10 very rare'

In [75]: re.search(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?/10', str_).group()
Out[75]: '23/10'
```

Comment: great, thanks, i have been using [0-9] for some time, never consider using \d